# jQuery.Form wont submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im´trying to submit a form without refreshing the page, but I´m having a problem.
When I click submit the page refreshes and anothing gets posted.
Here is the code, what am I doing wrong? (I´m a newbie)

jQuery 1.4.2 and the jQuery Form Plugin 2.43 is present.

tnx

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output2',
        url:       https://graph.facebook.com/<%=fbUid%>/feed,
        type:      post,

        clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
        //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

        // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
        //timeout:   3000 
    }; 

    // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#fbPostStatus').submit(function() { 
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It's **really worth** using a debugger like Firebug (for Firefox), Chrome Dev Tools (for Chrome), Microsoft Script Debugger or Visual Studio (for IE), etc., etc. to walk through your code. Any of those would reveal the script errors that Pekka and jAndy have pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotation marks in your `url` attribute:

```
 url:       https://graph.facebook.com/<%=fbUid%>/feed,
```

needs to be

```
 url:       "https://graph.facebook.com/<%=fbUid%>/feed",
```

that leads to a JavaScript error. Errors in the `onsubmit` function make the browser fall back to default behaviour (i.e. send the form the normal way).

And as @jAndy points out, `post` needs some quotes as well.

Comment: Actually the error is in `ready`, so the submit handler doesn't even get hooked up.

Comment: `post` needs some quotes aswell

Comment: I have quoted post and the url, and the site stops reloading. And the form seems to submit (well, the textarea clears), but nothing gets posted. I must investigate.